# Django admin precompile a field with current logged in user in add form

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In my django app i have a model like thisone:

```
class temp_case(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    main_id = models.ForeignKey(temp_main, related_name="tm_tc", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Main Template")
    descr = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Case description")
    dt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Created")
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='tcase_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="API Owner")
```

well, when i go in my admin interface ad add a row, i would that field owner (`models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='tcase_owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="API Owner"`) would automatically default populated with the current logged in user instead select it manually every time.

I have to manage my admin.py file? or directly into model?

so many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite [`ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options/#ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data):

```
#admin.py
class TempCaseAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {'owner': request.user}

admin.site.register(temp_case, TempCaseAdmin)
```